# Python nested loop: wrong output

Tags: python, list, nested

The task is to complete a code to label each app as "below average", "roughly average", or "better than average" depending on its rating. Inside the for loop,
If the app rating is less than 3.0, then label the app as "below average" by appending the string 'below average' to the current iteration variable. Else if the app rating is greater than or equal to 3.0 and below 4.0, then label the app as "roughly average" by appending the string 'roughly average' to the current iteration variable. Else if the app rating is greater than or equal to 4.0 label the app "better than average" by appending the string 'better than average' to the current iteration variable. Print app_ratings to see the results.

This is my code:

```
app=[]

app_ratings = [[
    'Facebook', 3.5],
    ['Notion', 4.0],
    ['Astropad Standard', 4.5],
    ['NAVIGON Europe', 3.5
]]

for app_ratings in app:
    app=[1]
    if app_ratings < 3.0:
        app.append('below average')

    elif   3.0 <= app_ratings < 4.0:        
        app.append('roughly average')

    elif app_ratings >= 4.0:
        app.append('better than average')

print(app_ratings)
```

Kindly advise on how I can correctly iterate over this nested list to achieve the correct output.

Comment: My output: [['Facebook', 3.5], ['Notion', 4.0], ['Astropad Standard', 4.5], 
    ['NAVIGON Europe', 3.5]]
    Expected output: [[‘Facebook’, 3.5], ‘roughly average’
    [‘Notion’, 4.0], ‘better than average’
    [‘Astropad Standard’, 4.5], ‘better than average’
    ‘NAVIGON Europe’, 3.5, ‘roughly average’]]

Comment: There are many things about the logic in the code that don't make any sense at all. Please start by thinking clearly about the intended purpose of each variable, and about what you expect to happen at each step of the code. We do not provide a debugging service.

Comment: Each loop makes a new `list` that replaces the old `list` bound to `app`. You populate it. Then you throw it away. And you never look at it again (even the final version of `app`). Maybe pay attention to the names you are using? Right now the code simplifies to "print the original stuff in `app_ratings`", which is clearly wrong.

Comment: For example: when you do `app=[]` at the start, what is the intended purpose of this? What will you use the variable `app` for, and why does it need to exist? Where you have `app_ratings = [[` etc., this is your input for the algorithm, right? What should the code do - do you want it to **change** `app_ratings` somehow, or create a **new** list, or just what? Exactly what should the result be?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `for app_ratings in app:`, exactly what do you think this means? How many times do you think the loop will run, and why? (Hint: what is the value of `app`, before the loop starts? What is your understanding of how a `for` loop works?) What should be different each time through the loop? What should happen the same way each time through the loop?

Comment: Aside from all of that: the title of the question does not make sense, because there is **no nested loop** in this code. (To make sure you understand: `if`/`elif`/`else` **do not make** any kind of loop.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. When I remove ```app = []```, I get the following error: (raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
NameError: name 'app' is not defined)

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Do not try to use the comment section to add information. Instead, [edit] the question. Again: there are many things that are wrong here, and you **can not** use Stack Overflow to post an assignment and talk back and forth with someone until you have working code. See also: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)

Comment: The intended purpose is to label the app as 'below average, 'roughly average' or 'above average'/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code is what you want. I think you want to append the 'average' string to the end of each element inside app_ratings list.

```
app_ratings = [['Facebook', 3.5],
    ['Notion', 4.0],
    ['Astropad Standard', 4.5],
    ['NAVIGON Europe', 3.5]
]

for app in app_ratings:
#app[1] is the score (3.5, 4.0,...)
#app is each element inside app_ratings (['Facebook', 3.5],...)
    if app[1] < 3.0: 
        app.append('below average')
    elif app[1] < 4.0:
        app.append('roughly average')
    else:
        app.append('better than average')

print(app_ratings)
#[    ['Facebook', 3.5, 'roughly average'],
#    ['Notion', 4.0, 'better than average'],
#    ['Astropad Standard', 4.5, 'better than average'],
#    ['NAVIGON Europe', 3.5, 'roughly average']
#]
```

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask. If everything is ok please accept my answer.